# Bitcoin Hash (Merkle) Tree implementation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, cryptocurrency, blockchain

I'm learning about how full nodes can send a Merkle root + a list of hashes, so that a light client can verify a transaction.

I couldn't find any good resources on how to implement it. I just knew what nodes I needed in order to verify a leaf, so I just found those nodes using DFS.

I'm sure there is a better way to construct the HashTree, find the list of nodes the light client needs, and verification algorithm. Therefore I would really appreciate it if you could review the algorithms and code and give me advice/guidance:

**HashTree.java:**

```
package core;

import static util.Bytes.SHA256;
import static util.Bytes.merge;
import java.util.Vector;

public class HashTree {
    private final HashNode root;

    public HashTree(byte[]... leaves) {
        final Vector<HashNode> hashes = new Vector<>();
        for (byte[] leaf : leaves) {
            hashes.add(new HashNode(leaf, null, null, null));
        }
        root = construct(hashes);
    }

    public byte[] getRootHash() {
        return root.hash;
    }

    public static byte[] getRootHash(byte[] hash, boolean oddHashIndex, Vector<byte[]> siblings) {
        for (byte[] sibling : siblings) {
            hash = (oddHashIndex) ? SHA256(merge(sibling, hash)) : SHA256(merge(hash, sibling));
            oddHashIndex = !oddHashIndex;
            for (byte b : hash) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%02X", b));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return hash;
    }

    /**
     * Performs a depth-first search to find a leaf in this HashTree.
     * If the leaf is found, construct a path with all the siblings
     * needed to verify the leaf.
     *
     * @param leaf to find
     * @return path, otherwise {@code null}
     */
    public Vector<byte[]> authenticationPath(byte[] leaf) {
        final Vector<HashNode> visited = new Vector<>();
        final Vector<byte[]> path = new Vector<>();
        if (!dfs(root, leaf, visited, path)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("could not find the given leaf");
        }
        return path;
    }

    private boolean dfs(HashNode current, byte[] target, Vector<HashNode> visited, Vector<byte[]> path) {
        boolean found = false;
        if (current.hash == target) {
            path.add(current.getSibling().hash);
            return true;
        }
        visited.add(current);
        if (current.left != null && !visited.contains(current.left) && !found) {
            found = dfs(current.left, target, visited, path);
        }
        if (current.right != null && !visited.contains(current.right) && !found) {
            found = dfs(current.right, target, visited, path);
        }
        if (found && current != root) {
            path.add(current.getSibling().hash);
        }
        return found;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new hash tree from the given leaves.
     * @param hashes (leaves)
     */
    private HashNode construct(Vector<HashNode> hashes) {
        if (hashes == null || hashes.size() < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("no leaves given");
        }
        if (hashes.size() == 1) {
            return hashes.firstElement();
        }
        if (hashes.size() % 2 != 0) {
            hashes.add(hashes.lastElement());
        }
        final Vector<HashNode> parents = new Vector<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < hashes.size() - 1; i += 2) {
            final byte[] parentHash = SHA256(merge(hashes.get(i).hash, hashes.get(i + 1).hash));
            final HashNode parent = new HashNode(parentHash, null, hashes.get(i), hashes.get(i + 1));
            hashes.get(i).parent = parent;
            hashes.get(i + 1).parent = parent;
            parents.add(parent);
        }
        return construct(parents);
    }

    private static final class HashNode {
        final byte[] hash;
        HashNode parent;
        final HashNode left;
        final HashNode right;

        private HashNode(byte[] hash, HashNode parent, HashNode left, HashNode right) {
            this.hash = hash;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        HashNode getSibling() {
            if (parent == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (parent.left == this) {
                return parent.right;
            } else {
                return parent.left;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HashTreeTest.java**:

```
package core;

import java.util.Vector;

import static util.Bytes.SHA256;
import static util.Bytes.merge;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class HashTreeTest {

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    void test() {
        final byte[][] leaves = new byte[][] {
            SHA256("ABC".getBytes()), // 0
            SHA256("DEF".getBytes()), // 1
            SHA256("GHI".getBytes()), // 2
            SHA256("JKL".getBytes()), // 3
            SHA256("MNO".getBytes()), // 4
            SHA256("PQR".getBytes()), // 5
            SHA256("STU".getBytes()), // 6
            SHA256("VWX".getBytes()), // 7
            SHA256("YZA".getBytes()), // 8
        };
        final byte[][] internal1 = new byte[][] {
            SHA256(merge(leaves[0], leaves[1])), // 0
            SHA256(merge(leaves[2], leaves[3])), // 1
            SHA256(merge(leaves[4], leaves[5])), // 2
            SHA256(merge(leaves[6], leaves[7])), // 3
            SHA256(merge(leaves[8], leaves[8])), // 4
        };
        final byte[][] internal2 = new byte[][] {
            SHA256(merge(internal1[0], internal1[1])), // 0
            SHA256(merge(internal1[2], internal1[3])), // 1
            SHA256(merge(internal1[4], internal1[4])), // 2
        };
        final byte[][] internal3 = new byte[][] {
            SHA256(merge(internal2[0], internal2[1])), // 0
            SHA256(merge(internal2[2], internal2[2])), // 1
        };
        final HashTree hashTree = new HashTree(leaves);
        final byte[] expectedRootHash = SHA256(merge(internal3[0], internal3[1]));
        final byte[] actualRootHash = hashTree.getRootHash();
        equals(expectedRootHash, actualRootHash);

        final Vector<byte[]> path = hashTree.authenticationPath(leaves[5]);
        equals(path.get(0), leaves[4]);
        equals(path.get(1), internal1[3]);
        equals(path.get(2), internal2[0]);
        equals(path.get(3), internal3[1]);
        assertEquals(4, path.size());
        equals(expectedRootHash, HashTree.getRootHash(leaves[5], true, path));
    }

    void equals(byte[] expected, byte[] actual) {
        assertEquals(expected.length, actual.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < expected.length; i++) {
            assertEquals(expected[i], actual[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Bytes.java**

````
package util;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public final class Bytes {
    public static byte[] merge(byte[]... bytes) {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            for (byte[] b : bytes) {
                stream.write(b);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    public static byte[] SHA256(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            final MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            return digester.digest(bytes);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Hello, I have seen `current.hash == target` where both elements are `byte[]` arrays, you meant to check if the two arrays contain the same elements in the same positions ?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed in your `Byte` class the following code:

```
public static byte[] merge(byte[]... bytes) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        for (byte[] b : bytes) {
            stream.write(b);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

You chose to print the error message on the console inside the try catch construct dismissing the `IOException` exception : this is a bad practice because you are loosing the possibility to communicate the unexpected behaviour to a generic user or system not monitorating the stdout channel. A possibility to handle the abnormal behaviour is to propagate the exception and let the user to decide how to handle it rewriting the `Byte` class methods:

```
public final class Bytes {
    
    public static byte[] merge(byte[]... bytes) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (byte[] b : bytes) {
                stream.write(b);
        }
        
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
    
    public static byte[] SHA256(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        
        return digester.digest(bytes);
    }
}
```

The first problem in your `HashTree` class is the use of the [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) class, as said in its documentation *unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector*, so you should instead use `List` and `ArrayList` inside all your classes.

In your `HashTree` class you have the following methods:

```
public HashTree(byte[]... leaves) {
    final Vector<HashNode> hashes = new Vector<>();
    for (byte[] leaf : leaves) {
        hashes.add(new HashNode(leaf, null, null, null));
    }
    root = construct(hashes);
}

public byte[] getRootHash() {
    return root.hash;
}
```

You can rewrite using `List` and the [`Arrays#copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-byte:A-int-int-) method to create a distinct copy of your `byte[]` array parameter to avoid the shallow copies of the references:

```
public HashTree(byte[]... leaves) throws Exception {
    final List<HashNode> hashes = new ArrayList<>();

    for (byte[] leaf : leaves) {
        hashes.add(new HashNode(Arrays.copyOf(leaf, leaf.length), null, null, null));
    }

    root = construct(hashes);
}

public byte[] getRootHash() {
    byte[] rootHash = root.hash;

    return Arrays.copyOf(rootHash, rootHash.length);
}
```

You have the following method in your `HashTree` class:

```
public static byte[] getRootHash(byte[] hash, boolean oddHashIndex, Vector<byte[]> siblings) {
    for (byte[] sibling : siblings) {
        hash = (oddHashIndex) ? SHA256(merge(sibling, hash)) : SHA256(merge(hash, sibling));
        oddHashIndex = !oddHashIndex;
        for (byte b : hash) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%02X", b));
        }
        System.out.println();
   }
   return hash;
}
```

Again the same problem of the stdout prints, you can create a different method to print the string representation of your roothash:

```
public String getRootHashString() {
    StringBuffer rep = new StringBuffer();
    byte[] rootHash = root.hash;
    for (byte b : rootHash) {
            rep.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    }

    return rep.toString();
}

public static byte[] getRootHash(byte[] hash, boolean oddHashIndex, List<byte[]> siblings) throws Exception {
    for (byte[] sibling : siblings) {
        hash = (oddHashIndex) ? SHA256(merge(sibling, hash)) : SHA256(merge(hash, sibling));
        oddHashIndex = !oddHashIndex;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

You can substitute `List` to `Vector` in your `authenticationPath` method :

```
public List<byte[]> authenticationPath(byte[] leaf) {
    final List<HashNode> visited = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<byte[]> path = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!dfs(root, leaf, visited, path)) {
       throw new RuntimeException("could not find the given leaf");
    }
        
    return path;
}
```

In your `HashTree` the main problem is about the operator you are using to compare `byte[]` arrays : instead of using the `==` operator you have to use the [`Arrays#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-byte:A-byte:A-) method. So you can rewrite your `dfs`  method like below :

```
private boolean dfs(HashNode current, byte[] target, List<HashNode> visited, List<byte[]> path) {
    if (Arrays.equals(current.hash, target)) {
        path.add(current.getSibling().hash);
        return true;
    }
        
    visited.add(current);
    boolean found = false;
    
    //found goes in the first position in every if    
    if (!found && current.left != null && !visited.contains(current.left)) {
        found = dfs(current.left, target, visited, path);
    }

    if (!found && current.right != null && !visited.contains(current.right)) {
       found = dfs(current.right, target, visited, path);
    }

    if (found && current != root) {
       path.add(current.getSibling().hash);
    }
        
    return found;
}
```

In the rest of your code including your test class I omitted for brevity you have just to substitute `Vector` with `List`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. But most of it is just to use List instead of Vector, some exception handling and equality checks. This is not what I was looking for. As I write in the original post, I'm mostly looking for improvements/guidance on the actual algorithms themselves.

Comment: @user644361 You are welcome.